Reduce size of BsDatePicker
Is there anyway to reduce the size (height and width) of BsDatePicker?
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview
I checked config properties but can't find one.

Do you want to change the size of the calendar, or the size of the input field?

size of the calendar pls. I am using minMode set to 'month' so it is actually a month-year picker.

I'm not sure what exactly do you want to shrink, but you got a whole bunch of classes for datepicker available mostly you should be interested in bs-datepicker-head and bs-datepicker-body. Add required styles to your main styles.css and it will work like a charm, just note that there're min-width/min-height set.
